# Which module is responsible for mobile menu in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.7

I need to check from which file the mobile menu comes in the admin panel.
I am searching it but not finding the particular file.

Please help if anyone knows about it .

Thanks,

Sarvagya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is `Mage_XmlConnect`. You can find the menu in `app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/etc/adminhtml.xml`

Comment: Thanks Marius you are a genius, you always have exact answer. Can you tell me one thing, as i have upgraded the website from magento 1.3 to 1.7 but this option is not coming on admin panel and this file with this menu is present where you specified.

Comment: I'm not really sure why is this happening. Make sure the module is enabled. Check app/etc/modules/Mage_XmlConnect.xml. If the file is there and the <active> tag is set to true, try clearing the cache.  Do you see the module in System->Configuration->Advanced?

Comment: Yes Marius the module is shown there in System->Configuration->Advanced and it is enabled i need to tell you that i have upgraded the website from magento 1.3 to magento 1.7

Comment: I understood that you just upgraded to 1.7, but I don't think it has something to do with this. Try to log the code in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu::_buildMenuArray(). Also check if you have access to the Mobile section (ACL). I have no other ideas on this.

Comment: Great !!!! Marius i found the problem it was related to ACL, sorry for posting late